# how can i return user in post method

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

This is my userlogincheck:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class UserLoginCheck
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string mobile { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
}

public HttpResponseMessage PostProduct(UserLoginCheck item)
        {


            User user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Mobile == item.mobile && 
              x.Password == item.password);

            string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = item.Id });
            var response = Request.CreateResponse<User> 
            (HttpStatusCode.Created,user);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);

            return response;
        }
```

i want to send mobile and password and return user that username and password equal to this username and password

i recive this error : System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 500 (Internal Server Error)
i call this method from xamarin mobile app
please help me

Comment: when you get a 500 that means there is an error on the server.  You need to look at the server logs to determine what is actually going wrong.

Comment: above code is in my server

Comment: I know that.  I said you need to look at the **logs** to get the root error.

Comment: It means there is problem in your API. Please debug your api method.

Comment: i debug api and no error in api

Comment: What is your request parameter?

Comment: passwords in clear in your database is a big security issue.